# Why column oriented file formats are not well suited to streaming writes?

Tags: hadoop, column-oriented

Hadoop the definitive guide(4th edition) has a paragraph on page 137:

> Column-oriented formats need more memory for reading and writing,
>   since they have to buffer a row split in memory, rather than just a
>   single row. Also, it’s not usually possible to control when writes
>   occur (via flush or sync operations), so column-oriented formats are
>   not suited to streaming writes, as the current file cannot be
>   recovered if the writer process fails. On the other hand, row-oriented
>   formats like sequence files and Avro datafiles can be read up to the
>   last sync point after a writer failure. It is for this reason that
>   Flume (see Chapter 14) uses row-oriented formats.

I don't understands why current block can not be recovered in the case of failure. Can someone explain technical difficulties about this statement:

> we can not  control when writes occur (via flush or sync operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> don't understands why current block can not be recovered in the case of failure.

Simply because *there is no block to recover*. The explanation is quite clear that the columnar formats (ORC, Parquet etc) *make their own decision when to flush*. If there was no flush then there is no 'block'. As Flume cannot control when the columnar memory buffers get written out to storage, it cannot rely on such formats.

Comment: So when we do a flush, it may be ignored by underlying storage format?

Comment: You don't understand that there is no flush, there is nothing to ignore.